# Неправильное преобразование типов c++ (через стек)

Tags: c++

Пушу в стек чар, содержащий число. После чего, создаю инт переменную, в которую попаю это самое число. В итоге оно сильно каверкается. Ниже приведу код самого попа и пуша.
(здесь на выходе получаю 53)

```
StackList<char> stack;
char number = '5';
stack.push(number);
int checking = stack.pop();
cout << checking << endl;
```

```
template <typename T>
void StackList <T> :: push (T x) {
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        head = new Node<T>(x);
        size++;
    } else
    {
        Node<T> *current = new Node<T> (x);
        current -> next = head;
        head = current;
        size++;
    }
}
```

```
template <typename T>
T StackList<T> :: pop () {
    if (!head)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        Node <T> *temp = head;
        head = temp -> next;
        T x = temp -> data;
        delete temp;
        size--;
        return x;
    }

}
```

Comment: Всё верно, орд '5' = 53, а если хотите получить 5, то стоит в char переменную класть  (или привести к char при выводе)

Comment: Каким боком здесь стек? `int x = '5'; cout << x;` дает тот же эффект.

Comment: http://book.itep.ru/10/ascii.htm Код символа `'5'` в десятичном представлении - 53... Так что все верно. Вы же выводите как `int`, так ведь?...

Answer (score 3):

```
char number = '5';
```

Данная команда помещает в переменную не число 5, а код, который соответствует символу «5». В данном случае ASCII-код символа «5» - 53.

Так что у вас ничего не коверкается, а работает именно так, как и задумано авторами языка.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы на выходе я получал не ASCII код , а число 5?

Comment: @РодионУльянов Либо присваивать не `'5'` а `5`, либо из получившегося числа вычесть `'0'`.

Comment: `char number = 5;`